# R all combinations of 3 vectors with conditions

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, combinations

I have two vectors

```
vector1 = c(0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5)
vector2 = c(10,20,30)
```

I now want all combinations of the elements in these vectors, while `vector2` is used twice. I use `expand.grid()`  to this.

```
combinations = expand.grid(vector1,vector2,vector2)
```

The result is a frame with the columns `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3`.

Now I want to combine the first vector with the second vector with some conditions.
E.g. 0.9 to 0.7 from `vector1` should only be combined with `Var2 >= Var3`. And 0.6 to 0.5 should only be combined with `Var2 <= Var3`.

How can I do this?

This is an example. The real number of combinations is about 18,000 elements with 3 decimals. So I am also looking for an efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just generate your grid, then subset. For example,

```
co = expand.grid(vector1,vector2,vector2)
subset(co, (Var1 >= 0.7 & Var1 <= 0.9) & Var2 >= Var3  )
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and I should have put that in my question.
This works, but I don't like it because it "ruins" the line numbering. Also I don't like the idea that I create the full data frame (real one is rather large) and then build subsets of it.

Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: **"ruins" the line numbering`** - if you meant rownames it can be reassigned using `rownames(co) <- 1:nrow(co)`. **real one is rather large** - how big, please clarify in your question.

Comment: About 18,000 elements with 3 decimals.

Comment: I have chosen this way then...
Thank you!